# How to count number of words from 2d array of sentences

Tags: c

I want to count number of words, and that value to be saved in an other 2d array.
This is what I have tried, but something is wrong.

```
int main()
{
    char ar[3][40] = {"Hello there hello helloo","How are you all.","Hello there"};
    printf ("%s", ar[2]);
    int i,c=0,k;
    for (k=0; k < sizeof(ar)/ sizeof(ar[0]);k++){
        if(strlen(ar)==1)//condition for 0 words
            printf("Number of words in array:=%d",c);

        else
        {

            for(i=0;ar[i][k]!='\0';i++)//loop for finding words
            {
                //checking for blank space,new line and tab
                if((ar[i][k]==32)||ar[i][k]=='\t'||ar[i][k]=='\n')
                c++;//incrementing count of words
            }

            if(ar[i][k]=='\0')
                c++;

            printf("Number of words=%d\n",c);//displaying counts of words
        }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you consider "I' as a word? You need to define the notion "word".

Comment: What is "something"?  Does it compile?  Does it give output that you do not expect?  Does it have a run time error?

Comment: You'll certainly have an error when you try to read `ar[3][0]`, so probably your mistake is just that you've written `ar[i][k]` instead of `ar[k][i]`

Comment: Ah thats exactly the problem! Thanks @WilliamPursell

Comment: @WilliamPursell And btw, what should I do for saving the number of words in to a 2d array instead of just printing it?

Comment: what do you mean you want to save the number of words in a 2d array? The number of words is just a value, like an `int` (as you have here), or better yet, `size_t`. You don't need a 1d array to store that, much less a 2d array. Also, it's better practice to compare against the actual `char` rather than its decimal value.. `if((ar[i][k]==' '` as you have for `'\t'` and `'\n'`

Comment: well I want later to do this:

Comment: if I have ```str1[0][200] = Hello how are you.``` have another array containing the value of number of words of that specific sentence. I want to do some maths with that certain value.